# autofocus not working second when trying to click input field for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a multi-step form using Bootstrap and jQuery. It has three sections and includes a progress bar to show the user's current status in the form process. The last two pages of the form work fine, however, the first section of the form (the email section) is not allowing the user to click the email input section a second time after the autofocus is removed once the page is loaded. For example, if they accidentally click on another part of the page and the autofocus is gone, they can't click on the field again to type. The other pages have the same code and are working fine with autofocus. I'm not sure why this is happening!

Here is a code pen:

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/adurante95/pen/eMgpOg/)  ([@adurante95](https://codepen.io/adurante95)) .

and then here is some of the code for the email section:

```
<div class="step">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-label-group form-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" contenteditable="true" autofocus>
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm just not sure why the field is not editable. I tried the contenteditable="true" attribute and that did not work either.

Comment: Never use contenteditable in input inputs are editable.

Comment: Didn`t reproduced at codepen, i was able to edit email after loosing focus.

Comment: shes added my fix in but didn't accept :( lol but yeah the fix is now in her code pen @ZufarMuhamadeev

Comment: sorry! i am new to stack overflow! lol - still trying to figure it all out but your solution 100% helped me! @JoeWarner

Answer (score 2):

This is because your label has position absolute and your input is display block meaning that the label element is above the input blocking access.

```
.form-label-group > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

but by adding  `pointer-events: none;` you're telling the browser to ignore any user input on this element and thus letting you access the input

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxrpWb working example

Comment: will this affect sending the data since the browser is ignoring user input?

Comment: not at all by ignoring user input i mean user clicks on the label, this wont affect the data at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your CSS. The input is refocused fine when using tab button. But label covers all the input field, so you are not able to click it. Remove `display: block;` and `width: 100%;` from the `.form-label-group > label` style.

**EDIT**

Another way is to focus input when label is clicked using jQuery.

```
$(".form-label-group label").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find("input").focus();
    });
```

Comment: that would still mean you wouldn't be able to click top left where the label is

Comment: @JoeWarner, didn't know that, thanks. Your answer looks much better.